# Viewport presists on changing screens

Tags: android, libgdx

My game I made is currently confusing, but it is long so I don't have the nerve to change it. So My PlayState is made without a camera and is made on the calculations of % od the WIDTH...

But now I made my MainMenu with the camera's and viewport's, because well, it was alot faster...

Now if I start the PlayState directly, it works normal. But if I start the PlayState from the MainMenu, the viewport seems to presist, and my game is totally weird. The 0,0 seems to be at middle, at none of the logic works...

So how do I reset the viewport? Or if I am correct, the setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined) seems to be still there. How to remove that?

Comment: Are you using Scene2D or is 3D? have you tried creating a new camera when changing screens?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your PlayState's `render` method, call

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

to reset the viewport to the full screen size. You also need to set the batch's projection matrix to whatever you were using when not using the MainMenu. If your PlayState does not use a camera, perhaps the matrix was set to the size of the screen, or perhaps it was an identity matrix. So you can use one of these:

```
spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

or

```
spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().idt();
```

Comment: Nice, it works, awesome, thanks... Although may I ask why doesn't it work if I give those 2 commands in the constructor??? Is there any need to call them more times?

Comment: There is only one OpenGL viewport for the entire app. Viewport objects modify it but don't automatically change it back to default. So your MainMenu's Viewport is modifying the OpenGL viewport and your PlayState is expecting the default one so you need to change it back each time you switch between the two. And if your two classes are sharing a single SpriteBatch (which they should to save memory and load times), then each must set the SpriteBath to be using the projection matrix it expects.

Comment: Also note that it is a bad idea not to use a camera or at least be manually calculating an adaptive projection matrix, because the screen dimensions vary dramatically between devices.

Comment: Ye when I started I did not read any tutorials just started programming, and made my own scaling, then I found out about cameras, but I already did the logic, so I did not change it. And also with the viewports I couldn't do what I wanted, because I made something different. But for future I am always gonna use viewports because it's alot easier to play with numbers than proportions!